# Отправка данных из одного модального окна в другое

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Делаю загрузку содержимого стандартными средствами bootstrap 3, и все открывается как положено и работает шустро, но у меня никак не получилось подвязать второе модальное окно. 
Идея такая - в первом окне форма, пользователь там чего-то выбирает, галочки ставит... потом жмет отправить и должно это окно закрыться а открыться другое с еще одной формой из одного инпута, там пользователь введ или не ввел данные не важно, а когда он уже во втором модальном окне нажал отправить - все улетело на почту (из первого и второго модальных окон).

Первое модальное окно вызываю так

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это именно модальное, а не popup окно и не фрейм, то, т.к. базовая страница у тебя при этом не перезагружается (если я правильно понял - и, в принципе, зачем ее перезагружать?), то по нажатии "отправить",  данные из 1го окна можно просто собрать и сохранить в памяти в какой-нибудь переменной (массиве), а потом, при нажатии "отправить" во втором окне - приплюсовать и к новым данным и уже вместе отправить. (Или поступить еще проще: в обоих модальых окнах показывать одну и ту же форму, только по частям (`<form><div#1/><div#2/></form>` - для 1го окна `div#1{display:block;} div#2{display:none;}`, для 2го - наоборот, а кнопка "отправить" в 1й форме - это не настоящий "submit", а обманка-переключатель между 2мя частями фомы)

Но, если это - popup окна или ifraame - тогда временные данные придется сохранять уже либо в куках, либо как уже писал здесь ранее Ilkinium (upd: кажтся, он удалил свой комментарий), на сервере с использованием сессии (отправляются 1е данные на сервер, но там они не отправляются на е-маил, а ждут прихода 2го пакета данных, либо, если то зачем-то нужно, отправляются в форму 2 го окна при ее запросе)

Comment: Хорошая идея насчет 2 форм в одном окне. Помогите кодик набросать))